# How to go about changing the assignment of a custom cell variable based on if and else-if statements after the variable is declared? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, casting, nstableviewcell

I’m trying to have a custom cell whom’s variable assignment changes based on `if` and `else-if` statements after the variable is declared.

This is to have the custom cell, which shows business hours of a selected business, be able to pick the `custom table view cell` that fits with the amount of open and closed time range pairs that I would like to show for the week for that business (as some businesses have more than one in one day).

However, I keep getting an error message saying:

“`Cannot assign value of type 'DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithTwoOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell' to type ‘DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell'`”

at this line of code:

```
detailsHoursContentsCustomCell = scrollableCitiesRestaurantDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithTwoOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithTwoOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell
```

which is the line of code within the conditional statement of the first `else-if` statement, which changes the variable assignment of the custom cell variable I’m using. This line of code has a comment above it with the error message it got in the code snippet further below in this post. The conditional statement in the `if-statement` before this `else-if` statement, sets the value as the same value that the custom cell variable starts out as, and doesn’t get this type of error message, or any type of error message in it’s conditional statement.

I also get this same error message in the other `else-if` statements’ conditional statements, where the custom cell variable value is changed. There are also comments above these lines of code saying the error message that was received for that particular line of code in the code snippet further below.

**What I’ve tried:**

-Investigated whether using “`as?`” or “`as`” instead of force casting (using “`as!`”) in the lines of code where I’m getting these same types of error messages, might work, but it seemed to me like it wouldn’t.

How can I fix this error message, and/or how can I go about doing what I’m trying to do if the way I’m currently trying to do it won’t work (with the “correct” code being used)?

Thanks!

The code is below.

**Code**:

`ViewController.swift:`

```
import UIKit

//*Some code for a view controller for a table view file.*

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        
        //*Code for this cell goes here.*
        
        return custumCell
    }

    //*More "indexPath.row" code goes here for other table view cells being used.*

    if indexPath.row == 10 {
        
        var detailsHoursContentsCustomCell = scrollableCitiesRestaurantDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell
        
        //If number of open hour time rnage pairs for all days is one.
        if selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.numberOfOpenHoursTimeRangesAsStringTypeOfTableViewCellToUse == "OneTimeRange" {
            
            detailsHoursContentsCustomCell = scrollableCitiesRestaurantDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell
        }
        
        //Else If number of open hour time rnage pairs for at least one day is two.
        else if selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.numberOfOpenHoursTimeRangesAsStringTypeOfTableViewCellToUse == "TwoTimeRanges" {
            
            //Below is the line of code where I get the error message: "Cannot assign value of type 'DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithTwoOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell' to type 'DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell'".
            detailsHoursContentsCustomCell = scrollableCitiesRestaurantDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithTwoOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithTwoOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell
        }
        
        //Else If number of open hour time rnage pairs for at least one day is three.
        else if selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.numberOfOpenHoursTimeRangesAsStringTypeOfTableViewCellToUse == "ThreeTimeRanges" {
            
            //Below is the line of code where I get the error message: "Cannot assign value of type 'DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithThreeOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell' to type 'DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell'".
            detailsHoursContentsCustomCell = scrollableCitiesRestaurantDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithThreeOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithThreeOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell
            
        }
        
        //Else If number of open hour time rnage pairs for at least one day is more than three.
        else if selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.numberOfOpenHoursTimeRangesAsStringTypeOfTableViewCellToUse == "GreaterThanThreeTimeRanges" {
            
            //Below is the line of code where I get the error message: "Cannot assign value of type 'DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithGreaterThanThreeOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell' to type 'DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell'".
            detailsHoursContentsCustomCell = scrollableCitiesRestaurantDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithGreaterThanThreeOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithGreaterThanThreeOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell
        }
        
        //Setting hours as labels.
        detailsHoursContentsCustomCell.sundayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.sundayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        detailsHoursContentsCustomCell.mondayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.mondayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        detailsHoursContentsCustomCell.tuesdayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.tuesdayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        detailsHoursContentsCustomCell.wednesdayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.wednesdayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        detailsHoursContentsCustomCell.thursdayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.thursdayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        detailsHoursContentsCustomCell.fridayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.fridayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        detailsHoursContentsCustomCell.saturdayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.saturdayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        
        return detailsHoursContentsCustomCell
    }
}

//*Some Extensions.*
```

The part of the model used for the business hours data that is shown in the detail view, after a restaurant is selected:

`DetailViewModel.swift:`

```
import Foundation

//*Other code for getting data such as name of restaurant, street address of restaurant, etc. for the detail view not using Codable. Am using NSDictionary.*

struct OpenHoursForDaysOfWeek {
    var mondayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var tuesdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var wednesdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var thursdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var fridayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var saturdayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var sundayOpenHoursWithoutDay: String
    var numberOfOpenHoursTimeRangesAsStringTypeOfTableViewCellToUse: String
}
```

**My Table View Cell Layouts:**

[AllDaysWithOneTimeRangeTableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQF2t.png)

[AtLeastOneDayWithTwoTimeRangesTableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7O30.png)

[AtLeastOneDayWithThreeTimeRangesTableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v70d.png)

Comment: Maybe the easiest thing after all is to copy the assignments at the end to each and every clause in that if/else and then create and return the variable in each clause. And personally I would use a `switch` instead of if/else.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you, I will try this. I originally had something similar to this, but without the returns in each if/else clause, and without the switch statements. Thanks for this! I’ll get back to you tomorrow if this works for me or not.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Message 1 of 2: I tried your suggested way of doing this, and still got error messages for using if and else-if statements, and when using the switch-case statements. These same error messages being: “`Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/ etc… [Project Name].app> (loaded)' with name ‘DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithGreaterThanThreeOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell`’”.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Message 2 of 2: I think your code still works, however, I keep getting this error message and when I comment out the code for this cell where its used, including the view controller where its used, I get this same error message but for another table view cell that’s for a different amount of open business hours time ranges. I’ve checked some things in my project that were suggested for this type of problem from researching this online, but haven’t come up with a solution yet. Thank you though for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without seeing your UI design, I'm assuming:

- the various cell types have some "common" UI elements
- the differences are related to hours of operation?

It is likely you could use a **single cell** design, and then show/hide the different UI elements as needed.

For example:

[image]

That image shows 3 different prototype cells.

However, the bottom cell has 3 "rows" in a vertical `UIStackView`. We could easily turn that into the first cell by hiding the 2nd and 3rd "row" and setting the yellow and cyan label text.

---

If you feel your layout / design is too complex, and you want to stick with multiple cell prototypes, then I'd suggest having the cell classes handle parsing the data...

So each cell could have a function like this:

```
    public func fillTheData(_ venue: VenueStruct) {
        sundayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = venue.hours.sundayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        mondayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = venue.hours.mondayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        tuesdayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = venue.hours.tuesdayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        wednesdayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = venue.hours.wednesdayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        thursdayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = venue.hours.thursdayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        fridayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = venue.hours.fridayOpenHoursWithoutDay
        saturdayHoursOpenWithoutDayLabel.text = venue.hours.saturdayOpenHoursWithoutDay
    }
```

Presumably, each cell type would have different labels.text to set.

Then your `cellForRowAt` looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        //*Code for this cell goes here.*
        return custumCell
    }
    
    //*More "indexPath.row" code goes here for other table view cells being used.*
    
    if indexPath.row == 10 {
        
        //If number of open hour time rnage pairs for all days is one.
        if selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.numberOfOpenHoursTimeRangesAsStringTypeOfTableViewCellToUse == "OneTimeRange" {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell
            cell.fillData(selectedVenueDetailViewInfo)
            return cell
        }
        
        //Else If number of open hour time rnage pairs for at least one day is two.
        else if selectedVenueDetailViewInfo.hours.numberOfOpenHoursTimeRangesAsStringTypeOfTableViewCellToUse == "TwoTimeRanges" {
            
            //Below is the line of code where I get the error message: "Cannot assign value of type 'DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithTwoOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell' to type 'DetailsHoursContentsForAllDaysWithOneOpenCloseTimeRangePairTableViewCell'".
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithTwoOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsHoursContentsForAtLeastOneDayWithTwoOpenCloseTimeRangePairsTableViewCell
            cell.fillData(selectedVenueDetailViewInfo)
            return cell
        }
        
        // and so on
    }
}
```

---

**Edit** - *after comments and seeing the layout goal...*

Now that I've seen your layout, this is a simpler task. It can be done with a single cell class, and no need to show/hide elements at all.

Two options:

- format each set of hours as an Attributed String
- use stack views

Each has its benefits and drawbacks... using an attributed string in a single label would be nice:

[image]

except --- there are differences in attributed strings between iOS versions. Somebody who is more familar with it might know how to work around that.

Using stack views is pretty straightforward.

Here's how it would look with yellow backgrounds so we can see the label framing:

[image]

and without the yellow:

[image]

I don't know how you are getting your data, so I made a `Venue` struct that looks like this:

```
struct VenueStruct {
    // assuming there are some other properties
    var venueName: String = "Some Venue"
    var venueAddress: String = "123 Main Street"
    // etc...
    
    // array of operating hours
    //  this will be filled with 7 [String] arrays (one for each day of the week)
    //  each of those arrays will have 1 or more time ranges
    var hoursArray: [[String]] = []
}
```

Example `hoursArray`s - when filled with data:

```
["11:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["11:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["11:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["11:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["11:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["11:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["11:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
-----
["7:00 am - 11:00 am", "12:00 pm - 10:00 pm"]
["10:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["7:00 am - 11:00 am", "12:00 pm - 10:00 pm"]
["10:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["10:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["10:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["10:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
-----
["7:00 am - 11:00 am", "12:00 pm - 4:00 pm", "5:00 pm - 10:00 pm"]
["10:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["7:00 am - 11:00 am", "12:00 pm - 4:00 pm", "5:00 pm - 10:00 pm"]
["10:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["10:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["10:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
["10:00 am - 10:00 pm"]
-----
```

So, here's a sample cell class - all via code, so no Storyboard or `@IBOutlet` connections:

```
class StackHoursCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier: String = "StackHoursCell"
    
    let daysFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .regular)
    let hoursFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .regular)
    
    let outerStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 8
        return v
    }()
    
    var dayNames: [String] = [
        "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    ]
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        // we want to get the longest "day string" so we can align the time "column"
        //  we could use "Wednesday" but let's assume we may localize the app and
        //  "Wednesday" may not be the longest string
        
        // we could try German for example where "Donnerstag" ("Thursday") will be the longest
        //var calendar = Calendar.current
        //calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
        //dayNames = calendar.weekdaySymbols
        
        var maxDayWidth: CGFloat = 0
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = hoursFont
        dayNames.forEach { sDay in
            v.text = sDay
            v.sizeToFit()
            maxDayWidth = max(maxDayWidth, v.frame.width)
        }
        
        // fill the vertical stack view with 7 "rows"
        //  - horizontal stack views, each with Day name and Hours labels as arranged subviews
        for _ in 1...7 {
            let rowStack = UIStackView()
            rowStack.alignment = .top
            // "padding" so we have space to the time column
            rowStack.spacing = 32.0
            // day name label
            let v1 = UILabel()
            v1.font = daysFont
            v1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: maxDayWidth).isActive = true
            // hours label
            let v2 = UILabel()
            v2.font = hoursFont
            v2.numberOfLines = 0
            v2.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            v2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            rowStack.addArrangedSubview(v1)
            rowStack.addArrangedSubview(v2)
            outerStackView.addArrangedSubview(rowStack)
            
            // during development, so we can see the label frames
            //[v1, v2].forEach { v in
            //  v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            //}
        }
        
        outerStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(outerStackView)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain outerStackView to the layoutMarginsGuid, with some
            //  left / top / bottom padding -- adjust to suit
            outerStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 24.0),
            outerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            outerStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            outerStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
    }
    
    public func fillTheData(_ venue: VenueStruct) {
        var str: String = ""
        var row: Int = 0
        for (d, a) in zip(dayNames, venue.hoursArray) {
            // always safely unwrap optionals
            if let rowStack = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[row] as? UIStackView {
                if let v1 = rowStack.arrangedSubviews[0] as? UILabel,
                   let v2 = rowStack.arrangedSubviews[1] as? UILabel {
                    v1.text = d
                    str = ""
                    a.forEach { hStr in
                        str += hStr
                        if hStr != a.last {
                            str += "\n"
                        }
                    }
                    v2.text = str
                }
            }
            row += 1
        }
    }
    
}
```

a simple sample data class to generate some sample values:

```
class SampleVenueData: NSObject {

    // various hours strings... just to make it easier
    //  to generate some sample data
    func hoursString(_ s: String) -> String {
        var str = ""
        switch s {
        case "11to10":
            str = "11:00 am - 10:00 pm"
        case "7to11":
            str = "7:00 am - 11:00 am"
        case "12to10":
            str = "12:00 pm - 10:00 pm"
        case "10to10":
            str = "10:00 am - 10:00 pm"
        case "12to4":
            str = "12:00 pm - 4:00 pm"
        case "5to10":
            str = "5:00 pm - 10:00 pm"
        default:
            str = "24 Hours"
        }
        return str
    }

    func sampleData() -> [VenueStruct] {
        
        var venueData: [VenueStruct] = []
        
        // some sample data
        var v: VenueStruct!
        
        v = VenueStruct()
        v.hoursArray = []
        for _ in 0..<7 {
            v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("11to10")])
        }
        venueData.append(v)
        
        v = VenueStruct()
        v.hoursArray = []
        
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("7to11"), hoursString("12to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("7to11"), hoursString("12to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        
        venueData.append(v)
        
        v = VenueStruct()
        v.hoursArray = []
        
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("7to11"), hoursString("12to4"), hoursString("5to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("7to11"), hoursString("12to4"), hoursString("5to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        
        venueData.append(v)

        v = VenueStruct()
        v.hoursArray = []
        
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("7to11"), hoursString("5to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("7to11"), hoursString("5to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("7to11"), hoursString("12to4"), hoursString("5to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("7to11"), hoursString("5to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("7to11"), hoursString("12to4"), hoursString("5to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        v.hoursArray.append([hoursString("10to10")])
        
        venueData.append(v)
        
        // replicate it a few times to confirm scrolling works
        venueData.append(contentsOf: venueData)
        venueData.append(contentsOf: venueData)

        return venueData
    }
    
}
```

and a sample view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var myData: [VenueStruct] = []
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        tableView.register(StackHoursCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: StackHoursCell.identifier)
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        // let's get some sample data
        myData = SampleVenueData().sampleData()
        
        myData.forEach { v in
            v.hoursArray.forEach { h in
                print(h)
            }
            print("-----")
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StackHoursCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! StackHoursCell
        c.fillTheData(myData[indexPath.row])
        return c
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Thanks for this! I didn’t know about the ability to hide UI elements in a table view cell. I’ll get back to you tomorrow as I’ll be away from my computer for the rest of the day. One or both of your solutions could work for me!

Comment: Message 1 of 2: Hi, thanks for your help earlier. I ended up going with the way/solution @JoakimDanielson mentioned above, as it achieved what I was trying to do, and for what you suggested about hiding UI elements in certain situations, I would also need to hide a few lines of empty space that would vary for certain circumstances between certain days of the week and their corresponding time ranges for the way I’m trying to present my UI elements here, and I’m not sure that could be done using the “hiding” ability as mentioned in your post.

Comment: Message 2 of 2: Regardless, this way of hiding UI elements could be used for my situation, but I’d have to abandon the way I’d like to show multiple time ranges for one or multiple days if this does occur, which I’d not like to do at this time. Big thanks though, glad I was able to learn about the “hiding” of UI elements ability!

Comment: @cg1000 - if you show me your cell layout(s), I can show you how to do this with a single cell class.

Comment: Yes, thank you that would be great! I just edited the post to include screenshots of the cell layouts.

Comment: @cg1000 - are you laying out your cells as Storyboard Prototypes or via code?

Comment: @cg1000 - and... if that's how your "different" cells look, you don't even need to hide/show anything. This can be done with multiline labels in stack views. Or, it could be done with an attributed string. Can you also show your data structure?

Comment: I'm laying them out as separate custom table view cells; not for sure if they're the same thing or are included/also referred to as Storyboard Prototype cells. They don't have the "Prototype Cell" moniker over them in the right panel of the Xcode screen to the right of the main code editor window.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I'm already using multiline labels but not stack views at the moment. I edited my post to include the model that includes the business hours info/data for the detail view, which doesn't use Codable. Is this what you mean by data structure? If not, let me know, and I can post what you need.

Comment: @cg1000 - do you have any other UI elements in the cells? Like "common elements" in the image I posted?

Comment: Apart from the labels for the days of the week, and the corresponding open hours time range(s) for each day of the week, no; the only common UI elements in this type of cell/these cells for the business hours contents is the day of the week labels, and the corresponding day of the week's open hours time range(s), for all days of the week. Each day of the week label, and each open hours time range(s) label for each day of the week are all separate and individual labels.

Comment: Message 1 of 2: Wow thank you, this is great! The way the times are being showed where there’s only one space after each previous open hours time range and the next day of the week and its corresponding only or first (if there’s more than one) open hours time range is what I would have preferred to use, but hadn’t figured out how to do that yet using .swift and .xib files, and `@IBOutlets` for each table view cell (the non-code approach).

Comment: Message 2 of 2: I think I know why my current code thats using @JoakimDanielson ’s way is having errors, so after I solve that, and later down the road, I’ll be switching to the way you showed me here. Thank you so much! Just one question, and you don’t have to write out the code for it, but is it possible to show the UI elements the way you did in your edited reply, still using one table view cell, using .swift and .xib files, and `@IBOutlets` for the table view cell (the non-code approach)? I don’t think there is, but I ask just for the sake of knowing/learning. Thanks!

Comment: @cg1000 - I put a project up on GitHub showing this using a Prototype cell in Storyboard so you can inspect the layout - https://github.com/DonMag/OpenHours

Comment: Thank you! I just took a look at the project, and it really helps. Thanks for all the help!